# Erro insert mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Como fazer o INSERT corretamente? Não está inserindo !

```
 $id =  $_GET['id'];
 $queryrun=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT image_path FROM tbl_image WHERE 
 id='$id' ");
 $row=mysqli_fetch_object($queryrun);
if($row->image_path!== $document)
 {
 unlink("upload/".$row->image_path);
 }
 $query = " UPDATE tbl_image SET image_album,image_text = 
'$img_album','$img_text',image_path = '$document' where id = '$id' ";
 $queryrun = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 $_SESSION['msg'] = "Your Data Updated Successfully";   
}
```

Duvida se no insert esta correto !

```
$query = " UPDATE tbl_image SET image_album,image_text = 
'$img_album','$img_text',image_path = '$document' where id = '$id' ";
```

Tentativa de especificar para cada valor ? mesmo erro

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_image SET image_album,SET image_text = 
'$img_album','$img_text',image_path = '$document'  ";
```

Resolvido desta maneira

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_image SET image_album = '$img_album', image_text = '$img_text', image_path = '$document'  ";
```

Comment: Aparece alguma mensagem de erro? veja se assim mostra alguma: `$queryrun = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn);`

Comment: nehuma mensagem de erro e nao insere !

Comment: Tem um update aí e não insert ;)

Comment: P cada coluna vc deve especificar um valor, o que não tem em todas no seu update.

Comment: e como seria especificar para cada valor ?

Comment: Assim `$query = "UPDATE tbl_image SET 
   image_album = 'valor',
   image_text = '$img_album',
   '$img_text',image_path = '$document'
   where id = '$id' ";` testou o código do primeiro comentário, não retornou erro?

Comment: testei sim! funciona assim $query = " UPDATE tbl_image SET image_album  = '$img_album',image_path = '$document' where id = '$id' "; dae eele insere mas eu queria adiconar mais uma tabela

Answer (score 2):

Se deseja incluir um novo registro com a [sintaxe alternativa](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) do MySQL deve especificar a coluna e o respectivo valor, conforme o código abaixo.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_image SET 
                      image_album = '$img_album' ,
                      image_text = '$img_text',
                      image_path = '$document'";
```

Ou na sintaxe classica:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_image (image_album, image_text, image_path) 
          VALUES ('$img_album', '$img_text', '$document')";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Tente da seguinte maneira:**

```
$query = " UPDATE tbl_image SET image_album='$img_album',image_text = 
'$img_text',image_path = '$document' where id = '$id' ";
```

*Sintaxe correta:*

> **UPDATE** table_name **SET** column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ... **WHERE** condition;